# compiling js failed React Native Expo TS working for IOS but not for android

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, compilation, expo

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2FEn.png)

I attempted to delete the node_modules directory, reinstall it, and launch a new emulator, but encountered the same error as shown in the screenshot. iOS functions properly; however, this issue arose after installing `expo install react-native-svg@12.1.1` and `expo install react-native-safe-area-context@3.3.2`, along with `npm i native-base`. Even after switching branches and cloning the project again, the errors persisted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats a problem on macos, you just need to restart your macbook, in my situation its helped